# Prove logical equivalence using laws of propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**$(p \rightarrow r) \vee (q \rightarrow r) ≡ (p\, \wedge \,q) \rightarrow r$**

Here is how I started:

> $(p \rightarrow r)\, \vee \,(q \rightarrow r) $

$(¬p \,\vee\, r) \,\vee\, ( ¬q \,\vee\, r)\,$  **using Conditional Law**

Stuck!!!

I can't apply de morgan and associative law for example.

I think there is a problem in question itself.

Comment: $\lor$ is associative and commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the right hand side,
$$(p \land q)\rightarrow r\equiv\lnot(p\land q)\lor r\equiv\lnot  p\lor\lnot q\lor r\equiv(\lnot p\lor r)\lor(\lnot q\lor r)$$

Comment: I have understood you answer 99% and removed my one confusion that it can also be proved using the R.H.S, Thanks! but just one question regarding the second last step. I think you applied Associative law in  **¬p∨¬q∨r**, but it gives this answer ¬p∨(¬q∨r) = ¬p∨(q →r). How you managed to get **(¬p∨r)∨(¬q∨r)**. I think you applied the commutative rule, but how? I'm little confused. Can you kindly elaborate? Thanks

Comment: @GhostRider This is using the property that $r\lor r\equiv r$. So, ¬p∨¬q∨r$\equiv$¬p∨¬q∨r$\lor r\equiv$(¬p∨r)∨(¬q∨r)
(p∧q)→r≡¬(p∧q)∨r≡¬p∨¬q∨r≡(¬p∨r)∨(¬q∨r). The relations you mentioned are _also correct_, just that the question asked you to show it equivalent to this form.

Comment: Appreciate for the reply. r V r ≡ r that's the idempotent law, but it has same variables unlike here with different variables ¬p∨¬q∨r V r. Even if it has the same variable let's suppose then I'm wondering how it is equivalent to (¬p∨r)∨(¬q∨r) and under which rule? Idempotent law? (which says the same variable). Apologize if you mind it.